# scatterLine using Kendo Chart - how to add error errorBars?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart, errorbar

I have my DoJo here http://dojo.telerik.com/oxoYE . I am struggling to find out a way to add error bar to this:

```
    function createChart() {
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            seriesDefaults: {
              type: "scatterLine",
              xErrorLowField: "low",
              xErrorHighField: "high",
            },
            series: [{
              data: [{x: 1.7, y: 11, low: 1, high: 3}, {x: 5.4, y: 8, low: 3, high: 6}, {x: 6.4, y: 13.4, low: 5, high: 7}]
            }],
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0},{1}"
            }
        });
    }
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/features/error-bars says error bar supported in scatter line.
Please help.

Thanks
Datha

Comment: copied the code from the link, and added tags

Answer (score 0):

Oops , I found answer http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/features/error-bars#bind-to-categorical-series 
I modified my DoJo http://dojo.telerik.com/oxoYE